# How to export overloads of a function in a C++ dll??

Tags: c++, dll, export

I am looking for a way to export from my C++ dll a function with two overloads.

This is my overloads on the .h file:

```
static __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall TotalCost(char* a, double* b);
static __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall TotalCost(char* a, double* b, double c);
```

my questions are:

- is it possible to export overloads of a function??
- how I can set in   the file .def the EXPORT ??

Thanks in advance 
Fabio

Comment: Yes it possible. And you can do it [*by ordinal*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278953%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and not by name. Or just include a header file with `dllimport` instead of `dllexport`.

Comment: is there a reason for 'static __declspec(dllexport)' ? Seems a contradiction to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export overloads.

The classic way is to add the following macro definition to your library headers:

```
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
  #define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #pragma comment(lib,"MYLIB.lib")
#endif
//...
```

Use the above macro in your interface files:

```
MYLIB_API int ComputeTotal(...
class MYLIB_API C_MyClass...
```

You will have to define `MYLIB_EXPORTS` in your DLL project settings (C++/Preprocessor Definitions).